# How do I setup Android Studio to use offline version of Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am on a slow internet connection and would like to use downloaded Gradle wherever possible rather than AS downloading it every time I build.

Now how do I setup AS for that?

Comment: For those who have access to internet on any other device, go to https://gradle.org/releases/ and download 'complete' version of the latest build. Extract it to **C:/Users/<username>/.gradle/wrapper/dists/** and set its path under **Use local Gradle distribution**. No need to touch **Global Gradle settings**.

Answer (score 1):

Hi welcome to stackoverflow, enjoy your stay.

To enable offline mode you can follow this steps:

> **Enable offline mode**
>
> If you are on a slow network connection, your
>   build times may suffer when Gradle attempts to use network resources
>   to resolve dependencies. You can tell Gradle to avoid using network
>   resources by using only the artifacts that it has cached locally.
>
> To use Gradle offline when building with Android Studio, proceed as
>   follows:
>
> Open the **Preferences** window by clicking **File > Settings** (on Mac,
>   **Android Studio > Preferences**). In the left pane, click **Build,
>   Execution, Deployment > Gradle**. Check the **Offline work** checkbox. Click
>   **Apply** or **OK**.
>
> If you're building from the command line, pass the
>   --offline option.

As shown here [Optimize your build speed](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#offline_mode)